# C# Cannot get subkeynames

Tags: c#

I am making a concept of registry viewer that gets all the names
 of the subkey in the registry and lists all the names in the console. and on the
`string[] subKeyNames = jdfddnjdz.GetSubKeyNames();`
i get an error which is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

here's the code.

```
RegistryKey jdfddnjdz = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"\SOFTWARE\Example\");
string[] subKeyNames = jdfddnjdz.GetSubKeyNames();
foreach (String val5 in subKeyNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val5);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Edit:
This code works fine but if I add `.OpenSubKey` like in the code above this it gives an error.

```
RegistryKey subKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
string[] subkeyNemez = subKey.GetSubKeyNames();
foreach (String valuef in subkeyNemez)
{
    Console.WriteLine(valuef);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: That horribly named variable is null.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  And add the null test.

Comment: `OpenSubKey` returns `null` when either the key does not exist or the application does not have access (not running as admin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it after a week! Just need to remove slash/Backslash on the "Software".

```
            RegistryKey jdfddnjdz = Registry.CurrentUser;
        jdfddnjdz = jdfddnjdz.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft");
        string[] dshg = jdfddnjdz.GetSubKeyNames();
        foreach(String umm in dshg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(umm);
            break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jdfddnjdz != null){
... your code
}
```

Comment: I need to get all the subkeys there.